# Updating user model mid-project how should I write view to save data to profile model

Tags: django, forms, django-models

[image]I'm trying to mimic this tutorial, specifically creating a Profile for a user: https://ruddra.com/posts/django-custom-user-migration-mid-phase-project/

However, I am unable to get it to work, how do I write the view to save form inputs into the Profile model. From the screenshot you can see that first_name, last_name, etc are not saving from the form input, even though they are required fields. The user "ddkl" get's created without any of the input information. I tried to input "John" , "Smith", "90210", etc, but nothing gets saved from the form. EDIT: FIGURED OUT IT'S SAVING THE FIELDS TO CORE USER MODEL. ANY IDEAS HOW TO GET IT TO ALSO SAVE TO PROFILE.

Django version == 2.2.3. Found out cannot use get_profile(), instead trying to use the signals:@receiver(post_save, sender=User).

Here is my Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    address1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True,
    help_text="zipcode")
    state = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=2, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 250, unique=True,
    verbose_name = 'email_address')
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    password = models.CharField(max_length =25, null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, omstamce, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

def __str__(self):   
    return f'{self.first_name} ({self.last_name}) ({self.email})'
```

Here is my views.py. It does not work, I cannot seem to save this model to profile.

```
def payments(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            # WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO SAVE TO PROFILE MODEL
            profile.user = request.user 
            profile.key = "".join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(20))
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! Please proceed to agreements and payment.')
            return redirect('agreements_page')
     else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
     return render(request, 'premium/payments.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
    Profile = get_user_model()

class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'zipcode', 'username']

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password2


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.zipcode = self.cleaned_data['zipcode']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Basically, I need help rewriting the part of the view that I commented.

Screenshot of issue: Data will not save, like email, first_name, Last_name.

EDITED: Should I get specify the model like? Or is there a better way:

```
Profile.objects.create(user=profile.user, first_name=form.cleaned.data['first_name'],...)
```

Comment: `profile.user = request.user`?

Comment: I don't think it will work, but I can try. I believe I tried that before.

Comment: This is the error that I get: create_user_profile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'omstamce'. This error occurs at profile.save()

Comment: you made a typo, it is `instance`, not `omstamce`.

Comment: Sorry, I did. The profile was made, but the data did not save. I'll add a screen shot  of what happened.

Comment: I mean in your signals you made an error: you wrote `omstamce` as parameter name, but it is instance in `create_user_profile`.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that. Sorry about that. I was playing around with the code for a couple hours and I must have changed that, but I'm still having the same problem of the data not saving. See the screenshot above.

Comment: Should I just write each individual field to model like: Profile.object.get_or_create(user=request.user, first_name=form.cleaned.data['first_name'], ...)